# Windows 11 with Phyton v3.10.x. ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backends (schannel) do not include compile-time ssl backend (openssl)

Tags: openssl, libcurl, pycurl

I am a windows 11 user with Python V3.10.9 I want to run pyload (python packages), but there is always an error

```
ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backends (schannel) do not include compile-time ssl backend (openssl)
```

I have tried several ways

**Experiment 1**

I tried install pyCurl with this way :

```
pip install pycurl
```

But there is an error like this :

```
Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
```

After that, i try download vcpkg from git and install curl[tool] with this way

```
vcpkg install curl[tool]
```

For build curl with libcurl.lib. I try

```
pip install pycurl --curl-dir="Path to Libcurl what i have installed"
```

But dont work with error message "**TRACEBACK RECENT CALL PYCURL**"

**Experiment 2**

I try to download file

```
pycurl-7.44.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
```

I forget where i download it, i try to install with this

```
pip install "path/to/pycurl-7.44.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl"
```

Install pycurl **SUCCESSFULLY**

But when I run **PYLOAD** get error message

```
ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backends (schannel) do not include compile-time ssl backend (openssl)
```

I have tried several alternatives installing openSSL for windows (v1.1.x) and add environment like PYCURL_SSL_CONFIG=openssl and etc..

But dont work. I confused about that.